# Android Glide Error:You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity

Tags: android, android-glide

i am using glide to view images which am getting as url from database in my activity,and i am deleting an image in activity where after deleting next activity will be opened but first time the image is deleting without any error,second time if  open to and press delete I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
```

This is my code to delete the image:

```
alert.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int i) {
                    try {
                        final Query postRef = ref.child("Pendingevents").orderByChild("Eventtitle").equalTo(Title);


                        postRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    child.getRef().removeValue();

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PendingEvents.class);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ApproveEvents.this, "Unknown      Error,please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog build=alert.create();
            build.show();
        }
    });
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
                                                                              at com.a.a.e.o.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.a.a.e.o.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.a.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at bootcamplearning.humanplanet.u.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.b.ol.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.b.qh.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.b.qn.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve]

Comment: Could you please add the full logcat as well with the section of code for Glide if you think that is the cause of the error?

Comment: Are you sure you don't start the load of the image from one activity that is then destroyed (for example rotating the device) before the load finishes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

It is better not to use the approach, described at the bottom of post.

The main idea is that Glide is concerned about lifecycle of an element where it works. If a `Fragment` or an `Activity` will be destroyed, Glide finishes its work for image processing. [Here is a detailed discussion of the issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/803).

To sum up, you should check if your activity is alive before calling `load` going back from some `AsyncTask` or other threads:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 && someActivity.isDestroyed()) {
    return;
} else {
    Glide.with(someActivity)
          .load(imageUrl)
          ....;
}
```

**Workaround**, not recommended because it will lead to some unnecessary processing if `Activity` was destroyed. But it is easy to use and makes its work.

In `Glide.with(context)` try to pass Application context instead of Activity. In this case you should not depend from Activity lifecycle.

For example, in activity you could use this:

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
      .load(imageUrl)
      .into(yourImageView);
```

Or in framgent:

```
 Glide.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
      .load(imageUrl)
      .into(yourImageView);
```

Comment: I think glide provide different context sources for a good reason. Should check if activity isDestroyed before do the load job.

Comment: Right, that way it is in the Workaround section

Answer (score 0):

In the fragment, use:

```
if(getActivity !=null) {
  Glide.with(getActivity())
    .load(imageUrl)
    .into(yourImageView);
}
```